# Populating dropdown menu - selected option from server

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am currently using knockout.js framework. I have taken a basic contacts form [example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html) and modified it to my own needs.  Each contact person has a status of `ACTIVE` or `INACTIVE`. In the status dropdown menu, I would like to show the selected status for the contact. Instead of getting two options, I am getting an usual select option list. How can I properly display a dropdown menu in knockout.js? [DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/insert_person.php)

**Edit per @haim770:**

```
    var ContactsModel = function (contacts) {
    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function (contact) {
    return {
            firstName: contact.firstName,
            lastName: contact.lastName,
            selectedOptionValue : contact.selectedOptionValue,
            phone: contact.phone,
            alt_phone: contact.alt_phone,
            main1: ko.observable(contact.main1),
            main2: ko.observable(contact.main2)
        };
    }));

    self.statusList = ['ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE'];

    self.addContact = function () {
        self.contacts.push({
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            selectedOptionValue : ko.observable("ACTIVE"),
            phone: "",
            alt_phone: "",
            main1: false,
            main2: false
        });
    };

    self.removeContact = function (contact) {
        self.contacts.remove(contact);
    };

    self.addPhone = function (contact) {
        contact.phones.push({
            number: ""
        });
    };

    self.removePhone = function (phone) {
        $.each(self.contacts(), function () {
            this.phones.remove(phone)
        })
    };

    self.save = function () {
            self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2));
        };


    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("");


};

$.getJSON("functions/getPerson.php", function(allData) {
          ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(allData));
});
```

HTML

```
<li>
<select data-bind="options: $root.statusList, value: selectedOptionValue"></select>
</li>
```

JSON

```
[{"firstName":"James","lastName":"Southerland","phone":"1234567890","statusList":"ACTIVE","alt_phone":"1234567890","main1":true,"main2":false},{"firstName":"Tina","lastName":"Turner","phone":"1234567890","statusList":"INACTIVE","alt_phone":"1234567890","main1":false,"main2":true}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**
The JSON returned from the server is malformed. Instead of setting the actual contact status in the `selectedOptionValue` (as you do in your `addContact` method), you return it as `statusOptionValues` field.

**2.**
No need to include the 'Active/Inactive' array (`statusOptionValues`) in every contact. Try this:

```
self.statusList = ['ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE'];
```

Then change your binding declarations appropriately:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.statusList, value: selectedOptionValue"></select>
```

**3.**
You better rely on a `boolean` field instead of array of `string`:

```
contact.isActive = ko.observable(true);
```

Comment: Not getting the correct selected value, check my edit question for the changes I made accordingly to your response.

Comment: Show the html as well. did you fix the JSON?

Comment: Yes I did. I have Added the html and JSON to the edited question.

Comment: I do see 'ACTIVE/INACTIVE' in the drop-down now. What's wrong?

Comment: Yes, but the selected value for second contact person is incorrect. It is to show "INACTIVE" and not "ACTIVE".

Comment: Your JSON is still incorrect. It should have `selectedOptionValue:"ACTIVE"` not `statusList:"ACTIVE"`. `statusList` doesn't change and is only part of the View-Model, not the data returned/passed to the server.

Comment: Alright great thanks! What did you mean by option 3? How to implement?

Comment: Change your JSON to return `isActive` (true/false) and your `select` drop-down to `<input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: isActive" />`.